# Where is Privacy Guard in Cyanogenmod 10.1? The setting seems to be missing

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-nexus-s, privacy

My phone is the Google Nexus S and I am running the latest stable Cyanogenmod build (10.1.2-crespo).

I have installed Cyanogenmod especially because of the **Privacy Guard** feature, but now I cannot find and enable it anywhere in *Settings > Apps*.

Is it possible that this feature is not included in all official Cyanogenmod builds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Privacy Guard is not available on stable builds, only on nightlies.

[Source](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/75297-what-happened-to-the-privacy-guard/#entry398669):

> Privacy guard probably won't make it to the stable build until the
>   next major release (10.2).

Comment: Ok, that explains everything. Thanks for help!